# Windows 10 Linux subsystem - Python - String to computer clipboard

Tags: python, windows, clipboard

I have a python script where I want to place a string in the computer's clipboard.  I have this working in Linux, Mac, and previously in Windows using cygwin.  I had to modify one line of code to get it working in the respective systems.
I can't get a string copied to the clipboard on Windows 10's native Linux subsystem.
The line below causes error: sh: 1: cannot create /dev/clipboard: Permission denied.  Any idea how to modify this line?

```
os.system("echo hello world > /dev/clipboard")
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `/dev/clipboard` in linux, that's something that only exists in cygwin. Usually programs like `xclip` or `xsel` are used to access the X server clipboard on linux, but I'm relatively sure that won't work on the windows linux subsystem.

Comment: Do you need a solution for Windows in general, in which case it would be normal to use python.exe built for Windows, or a solution specifically when running Linux python under WSL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the clipboard contents on Windows you can use [`win32clipboard`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/win32clipboard.html):

```
import win32clipboard
win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
cb = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
```

To set the clipboard:

```
win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
# win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard() # uncomment to clear the cb before appending to it
win32clipboard.SetClipboardText("some text")
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
```

If you need a *portable* approach, you can use [`Tkinter`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter), i.e.:

```
from Tkinter import Tk
r = Tk()
r.withdraw()
# r.clipboard_clear() # uncomment to clear the cb before appending to it
# set clipboard
r.clipboard_append('add to clipboard')
# get clipboard
result = r.selection_get(selection = "CLIPBOARD")
r.destroy()
```

---

Both solutions proved to be working on Windows 10. The last one should work on Mac, Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one lib

```
**pip install clipboard**


import clipboard
clipboard.copy("abc")  # now the clipboard content will be string "abc"
text = clipboard.paste()  # text will have the content of clipboard
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also the [pyperclip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyperclip) library. I use this in a couple of tools and it does a great simple job.